Dependency problem installing tensorflow and protobuf
user@Z690P:~/dev/puff$ poetry add protobuf
Using version ^5.27.0 for protobuf

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.5s)

Because tensorflow (2.16.1) depends on protobuf (>=3.20.3,<4.21.0 || >4.21.0,<4.21.1 || >4.21.1,<4.21.2 || >4.21.2,<4.21.3 || >4.21.3,<4.21.4 || >4.21.4,<4.21.5 || >4.21.5,<5.0.0dev)
 and no versions of tensorflow match >2.16.1,<3.0.0, tensorflow (>=2.16.1,<3.0.0) requires protobuf (>=3.20.3,<4.21.0 || >4.21.0,<4.21.1 || >4.21.1,<4.21.2 || >4.21.2,<4.21.3 || >4.21.3,<4.21.4 || >4.21.4,<4.21.5 || >4.21.5,<5.0.0dev).
So, because puff depends on both tensorflow (^2.16.1) and protobuf (^5.27.0), version solving failed.

In my understanding, poetry should select a compatible version for the package being added: why do I need to manually choose a version in this case?
Moreover after selecting version ">4.21.4,<4.21.5" I later have the same issue with grpcio-tools:
user@Z690P:~/dev/puff$ poetry add grpcio-tools
Using version ^1.64.0 for grpcio-tools

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.5s)

Because no versions of grpcio-tools match >1.64.0,<2.0.0
 and grpcio-tools (1.64.0) depends on protobuf (>=5.26.1,<6.0dev), grpcio-tools (>=1.64.0,<2.0.0) requires protobuf (>=5.26.1,<6.0dev).
So, because puff depends on both protobuf (^4.21.4) and grpcio-tools (^1.64.0), version solving failed.

is it a problem with poetry or with tensorflow?
